# parser from different streams

Tags: c, bison, lex

We need to parse a value accordingly to this grammar:

```
%{
    ...
    #define YYSTYPE Pformatted
    extern FILE *formattedin;
    extern Value lexval;
%}
%token FORMATTED_LEX_ID CHARCONST INTCONST REALCONST STRCONST BOOLCONST     FORMATTED_LEX_ERROR
%%

formatted_string : formatted 

formatted   : atomic_formatted
            | struct_formatted
            | vector_formatted

atomic_formatted    : CHARCONST
                    | INTCONST 
                    | REALCONST
                    | STRCONST 
                    | BOOLCONST

struct_formatted :  '(' attr_list ')' 

attr_list   : attr ',' attr_list 
            | attr

attr : FORMATTED_LEX_ID  formatted 

vector_formatted : '[' formatted_list ']' 

formatted_list  : formatted ',' formatted_list 
                | formatted
%%

int yyerror(){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error while parsing the formatted values.\n");
    return -1;
}

void parse_formatted(FILE* stream){
    formattedin=stream;
    yyparse();
}
```

this is the lex

```
%{
#include <stdlib.h>
...

Value lexval;
%}
%option noyywrap
spacing     ([ \t])+
eol         \n
letter      [a-zA-Z]
digit       [0-9]
id          {letter}({letter}|{digit})*:
num         {digit}+
sugar       [\(\)\[\]".":,;]
charconst   \'.\'
intconst    -?{num}
realconst   -?{num}?"."{num}
boolconst   (true|false)
stringconst \"([^\"])*\"

%%
{spacing}       ;
{eol}           return -1;
{boolconst}     {lexval.cval = (yytext[0] == 'f' ? '0' : '1'); return(BOOLCONST);}
{intconst}      {lexval.ival = atoi(yytext); return(INTCONST);}
{realconst}     {lexval.rval = atof(yytext); return(REALCONST);}
{charconst}     {lexval.ival = yytext[1]; return(CHARCONST);}
{stringconst}   {lexval.sval = insert_str_c(yytext); return(STRCONST);}
{sugar}         {return(yytext[0]);}
{id}            {yytext[strlen(yytext)-1]=0; lexval.sval = insert_str_c(yytext); return FORMATTED_LEX_ID;}
.               {return (FORMATTED_LEX_ERROR);}
```

the problem is that we need to parser it from file or from the stdin, calling either `parse_formatted(file_name)` or `parse_formatted(stdin)`

It seemed to work at first, but if there is a read from file followed by a read from the stdin, this doesn't work anymore...it seems to enter the function `parse_formatted` but the `yyparse` doesn't recognize anything.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only change input sources by reassigning `yyin` if the previous source actually reached the end-of-file. Or, to be more precise, the current input buffer will continue to be used by the lexer until it is exhausted, and only then will data be read from the input source. In order to discard the current input buffer and switch input sources, you can use `yyrestart` (see the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/User-Values.html#index-yyrestart).)

Alternatively, you could use the `YY_FLUSH_BUFFER` [special action](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Actions.html#index-flushing-the-internal-buffer) in your lexer action for newline.

See the [Bison FAQ](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/How-Can-I-Reset-the-Parser.html) "How Can I Reset the Parser?" for a longer discussion with examples.